# Facebook sdk4 php switch User feature

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a site to manage Facebook Feeds and is using facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev.I have the user Login and access token saved to database functionality working properly.

I need to show Switch Facebook User account Option, If he is already logged into facebook account. Currently if he is logged into facebook account on another tab. There will not be facebook authentication, It just shows App Permissions window and then completes facebook login process.

But I found that this option is available in Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK example...A pop up come up for Login and you can switch user on top right side.

Please let me know how to accomplish this in PHP sdk 4 or work around, or am I missing something here.

Thanks in advance....
 Please see this screenshot

https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t39.2178-6/10574702_711575178930859_1600770327_n.png

I have added a screenshot where JavaScript SDK show switch user button (top right side)when user is logged in to facebook account in another browser tab.(this comes up as pop up)

But there is no such option when using php sdk. instead of pop up, its come as a webpage and it does not have switch user account.

Comment: One user is only allowed to have one account.

Comment: does anyone know how to implement this.... I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days...

Comment: Why do you want to implement something that would only be needed if the user is doing something against Facebook Policy?

Comment: oh... what do you mean by 'against Facebook Policy'. Switch user account feature is available in Javascript SDK example...This would be helpful in letting know the users from which fb account they are going to connect.. If the account belongs to someone else who sat before him, he can switch user account to his...

Comment: I meant it sounded like the same user would login as different Facebook users. That is not allowed.